# Vim start working slow after some time

Tags: vim, macvim

I use MacVim (8.0.1633) for a while and faced with strange behavior: when i start vim - it works just fine, but it slows down after 3-4 hours of work. Is it normal behavior?

Comment: Just a couple of hints: 1. Look at https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2875/vim-slows-down-over-time-with-syntax-on; 2. If the HOME variable has a network path, try to set it to a local path for the running vim instance.

Comment: Local path is ok. And first thing is a report about syntax which is not really a solution